# PHP. Filtering data in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, orm, filtering, eloquent

I'm trying to delete some elements from object taken from DB with Eloquent.

I have an object assigned to variable $words

```
$words = Word::all();
```

When I'm displaying $words as JSON it looks like so:

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"word": "dog",
"phonetic": "dog",
"mean": "pies",
"assoc": "some example text",
"author_id": "3",
"user_id": "3"
},
{
"id": "2",
"word": "sun",
"phonetic": "sun",
"mean": "słońce",
"assoc": "lorem ipsun dolor sit amet",
"author_id": "3",
"user_id": "2"
}, ...
]
```

What I want to do is remove from whole object those entities which have, for example, value "user_id" set on 2, 4, or 5. This id's are stored in an array.

What's the best method to achieve it with Eloquent ORM? Using Word::where(...) isn't enough because, as far as I know, it can take only one value. I was trying to do it with foreach loop's but past iterating the object $words returned with no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand your question clearly, but you can use where statement as a closure and use your foreach loop inside if you want to bind more than one where statement.

Something like this may work;

```
$result = Word::where(function($query) use ($words) {
    foreach($words $k => $v)
    {
        //Whatever you want to bind into where
        $query->where($v, '=', 1);
    }
})->delete();
```

Comment: Maybe wasn't understandable enough. Sorry. I wan't to filter object: remove entities only from object which I'm passing to client side, not delete them from database.

Comment: At least I used something like that:
`$words = Word::all();

$result = Word::where(function($query) use ($words){
  foreach ($words as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($idArray as $key) {
    $query->where('id', '!=', $key);
   }
  }
 })->get();`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `where_not_in()`?
http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent

Like this:

```
DB::table('users')->where_not_in('id', array(2, 4, 5))->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Eloquent with Slim framework, not whole Laravel.